# Javascript regular Expressions cut off last parameters between slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm new to regex and can't find a proper solution for this:

I want to cut off the last parameters of the url between the two slashes "/1032/" form url "http://www.blablabla.com/test.php/addpage/1032/"

That i have just http://www.blablabla.com/test.php/addpage/  ...though this part is not important of being matched...so just cut off the parameters between the last slashes...

What i did was:

```
curr_url= "http://www.blablabla.com/test.php/addpage/1032/";
expression =/.*\/./;
alert(expression.exec(curr_url));
```

Result is  "http://www.blablabla.com/test.php/addpage/1"
Now i could cut off the last parameter by a slice but thats not reasonable i guess

Any better solutions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: /^*\/$/  I guess that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curr_url.match(/.+(\/.+\/)$/)
```

["http://www.blablabla.com/test.php/addpage/1032/", "/1032/"]

First greedy `.+` captures everything to last slash and then backs off to next-to-last, because rest of pattern would fail otherwise. () capture everything between this slash and last an then `\/$` at the end tell that string should end after last slash. Move slashes outside brackets if you only want number itself.

It seems though I misinterpreted your intent. If you need first part of string, you can use regexp suggested bellow with a little change:

```
curr_url.match(/(.+)\/.+/)[1]
```

It captures "everything until slash, and then some more". It will first reach last slash in string, but then back off to previous slash, because there's not "then some more", thus leaving exactly the part of string you want.

Comment: thaks for answering..that returns the params between the slashed twice...;-(

Comment: No, it doesn't. It returns an array. 0th index is full match and 1st is the string caught with () capture, which is "/1032/". Try `var result = curr_url.match(/.+(\/.+\/)$/); alert(result[1]);`

Comment: okay could you tell me how i can manage to get just  http://www.blablabla.com/test.php/addpage/ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var parts=curr_url.split('/');
```

After that you can get any part from the array.

Answer (score 1):

In your expression

```
/.*\/./
```

you need the last dot to tell the pattern that there is a character after the slash following, but this is also matched and therefore in your result. If you remove it it will match till the last slash, so no solution.

But there is a way to define what should be after the pattern and to not match that stuff. Its called a [look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

So you could do

```
/.*\/(?!$)/
```

and `(?!$)` is a negative lookahead assertion that means "Match the previous slash only if the end of the string (the `$`) is not following".

```
curr_url= "http://www.blablabla.com/test.php/addpage/1032/";
expression =/.*\/(?!$)/;
alert(expression.exec(curr_url));
```

Would return also what you want.